# Newbie trying to Learn Cucumber and Ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I am trying to execute step 2 in the Calculator project in the book "The Cucumber Book". I have tried to following the previous answer given in this form to use the backtricks instead of the single quotes but I am still getting the same error message below:

```
.F-

(::) failed steps (::)

undefined method `success?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
./features/step_definitions/calculator_steps.rb:7:in `/^the calculator is run$/'
features/adding.feature:5:in `When the calculator is run'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/adding.feature:3 # Scenario: Add two numbers

1 scenario (1 failed)
3 steps (1 failed, 1 skipped, 1 passed)
0m0.002s
```

This is the exact step information as I found on your forum previously:

```
Given /^the input "([^"]*)"$/ do |input|
  @input = input
end

When /^the calculator is run$/ do
  @output = `ruby calc.rb #{@input}`
  raise('Command failed!') unless $?.success?   
end

Then /^the output should be "([^"]*)"$/ do |arg1|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Ruby installation have you got?

Comment: 1) Does the file calc.rb have executable permissions for all users?  2) Does calc.rb have a shebang line at the top? And they are called _backticks_...no tricks involved.

Comment: 3) I think you might be having path problems.  Try using the full path to the file calc.rb.  4) The ruby global variable $? contains the exit status of the last child process's exit status--or nil by default.  Because your error says you are calling success on nil, that means that $? is nil, which means your ruby process in the backticks never executed.

Comment: Full path like this:  Rails.root = /path/to/your_app, and if calc.rb is in /path/to/your_app/tests/helpers  then you can write the full path as: `"#{Rails.root}/tests/helpers/calc.rb"`

Comment: I am using Ruby 2.0.0.0-p247

Comment: 7stud, Obviously the backtricks was a typo. Thanks for catching that. :) Anyway, the calc.rb file is currently empty as the directions say to just create the file empty for now to see that the cucumber test passes.

Answer (score 0):

calc.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# install bc with 'sudo apt-get install bc'

if ARGV.size > 0
    command='echo ' +  ARGV.join('') + ' | bc'
    exec(command)
end
...
Now my cucumber output looks like:
auser@worker1:~/cucumber/calculator# cucumber
Feature: Adding

  Scenario: Add two numbers       # features/adding.feature:2
    Given the input "2+2"         # features/step_definitions/calculator_steps.rb:1
    When the calculator is run    # features/step_definitions/calculator_steps.rb:5
    Then the output should be "4" # features/step_definitions/calculator_steps.rb:10

1 scenario (1 passed)
3 steps (3 passed)
0m0.021s
```